# Convert Postman Collection to PDF

Tags: asp.net, postman, postman-collection

I've developed a pretty extense API, and I have it on Postman, which works pretty nice. Now I have to generate an html doc to keep it versioned inside /docs along with my sources.

Is there a tool or a way to achieve this? I really don't want to write all this documentation.I don't want to use Postman publish docs also. Sharing the postman collection is not an option
How can we convert Postman Collection to PDF/Word document?

Answer (score 14):

You can publish the documentation of your collection through postman :

1. Click on the **...** -> Publish Docs.

[image]

This will open a new page to postman website in which you can preview your documentation[image].

2. Click on Preview Documentation, it will open a new page as the html version of the documentation.
3. Right click to display chrome option Print it
   [image]

This will provide you the option to save it as a pdf

[image]

This answer was inspired from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29238120/creating-html-doc-from-postman-collection) for Creating html doc from postman collection.

Comment: Thanks for response. I have tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29238120/creating-html-doc-from-postman-collection but not find any proper solution.

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth; My answer it may be not enough detailed but it wasn't wrong. I have edited it to proof it validity.

Comment: Note, In a more recent version, you must be registered and have access to a workspace. From the Workspace follow the steps in this post, except select 'View Documentation" -> "Publish" instead.

Answer (score 5):

The best I've found is Postman to HTML (properly, not file > save)

1. Install this anywhere in your PATH: https://github.com/aubm/postmanerator
2. Right click on your collection in Postman and click export, which will give you a JSON file
3. Run `postmanerator -output=/var/www/public/api.html -collection=/var/www/my-collection.json` in cli

You can create your own themes too which collectively is what we all want to be able to do straight out of Postman

Answer (score 0):

I was trying for ever to get this in the desktop app, preview is not there.  But It is there when I log into the postman web app.

Answer (score -1):

For newer versions of postman try this

1. Go to your collection
2. Right click the collection and go to "View Documentation"
3. Then top right hand corner, press "Publish"

[image]

Comment: I don't think that it will give you pdf format... Publish just generates a public URL of API EPs

Answer (score -3):

You can also get the PDF version by clicking :

[image]

Comment: I'm looking at our screen and that option is not there. So is this for all accounts or just for paid ones?